# Get GlassFish jdbc pool settings from java code programmatically

Tags: java, glassfish

I create JDBC Connection pool for my Oracle db inside GlassFish admin console.
This pool has some properties, including `URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.250:1521/MYDB`

I'd like to read this jdbc property from my java code (I use web project + ejb, simplified packaging inside .war file).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the information you are looking for in the domain's XML file, usualy located at: %glassfish_home_directory%\glassfish\domains\%NAME_OF_YOUR_DOMAIN%\config\domain.xml

you can easily parse it using java's built in support for XML parsing, such as DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the embedded API to run the asadmin command to get results. Check out this blog entry using the CommandRunner object:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhavanishankar/archive/2011/09/12/embedded-glassfish-programatically-running-asadmin-commands-servlet

perhaps you can try "list-jdbc-resources" or similar asadmin command to get the data.

Hope this helps.